# In Python DataFrame how to find out number of rows that have valid values of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I want to find the number of rows that have certain values such as `None` or `""` or `NaN` (basically empty values) in all columns of a DataFrame object. How can I do this?

Comment: `df.isnull().any();df.eq('').any()`
`

Comment: If you only need to know how many nulls, df.info() will give you non-null counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `pandas.Series` (think of it as the column of a normal `pandas.DataFrame`):

```
>> s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, np.nan])

>> s

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    NaN

>>  s.isnull().sum()

  3
```

For a `pandas.DataFrame` is quite similar:

```
>>  pd.DataFrame(np.array([[np.nan, np.nan],
 ...:        [ 0., np.nan],
 ...:        [ 1.,  1.],
 ...:        [ 2.,  2.],
 ...:        [np.nan, np.nan]]))

>> df

     0    1
0  NaN  NaN
1  0.0  NaN
2  1.0  1.0
3  2.0  2.0
4  NaN  NaN

>> df.isnull().sum(axis=0)

0    2
1    3
dtype: int64
```

To sum by row, just put `.sum(axis=1)`.

Comment: What should I do if I want to do a `isnull()` alongwith `eq(empty_value)` and get the results for both together?

Comment: For a quicker method, and as you want to count them all together, I would recommend you converting all empty values to NaNs so you can sum them. You can do it by: `s.replace("", np.nan)` or `df.replace("", np.nan)`. And then apply the method above.

Answer (score 3):

Use pandas dataframe.isin to create a boolean array.  Sum by row, then find
the number of rows with a result > 0.

Place one or more values in the search_values list to look for within the rows of the dataframe.

```
search_values = ['', np.nan, None]
(df.isin(search_values).sum(axis=1) > 0).sum()
```

If you would like the row count per column:

```
df.isin(search_values).sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Im having a field in database which appear only in some records and its not present in other records. However, I'm not getting the count of how many records its not present in. How can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.isnull().sum()` to get number of rows with `None` and `NaN` value.

Use `df.eq(value).sum()` for any kind of values including empty string `""`.